# Can you have multiple Working Holiday Visas (WHV) in Europe?

Tags: visa, schengen, working-holiday-visas

Can you you have let's say a 1 year working holiday visa in Netherlands and a 1 year working holiday visa in Germany, Belgium, Estonia etc. at the same time? or can you only have one at a time?

Comment: Why would you want to? Do you want to hold down two jobs at the same time in two different countries?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike short-term Schengen visas, long-term visas in the EU are regulated by each member state individually. This means that you can have as many long-term visas for Europe as you want, without anyone batting an eye. There are some exceptions to this, but they only kick-in for permanent residencies and family members of the EU.